# Llamar datos de una hoja en especifica VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba

Buen dia me gustaria que me ayuden como puedo hacer para extraer datos a un formulario de un hoja en especifica:

tengo este codigo pero solo me busca de los datos de la hoja activa. me gustaria especificar la hoja donde buscar.

```
Cells.Find(what:=txtDni.Text, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Me.txtArea.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
Me.txtCargo.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
Me.txtEvaluador.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
Me.txtFecIng.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
Me.txtNombre.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
Me.txtSede.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debería servirte, deberías intentar evitar el uso de `.Activate` o `.Select` ya que siempre dan lugar a errores:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet 'declaras una variable de hoja
    Dim C As Range 'no utilices .Activate, utiliza una variable de rango.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MiHoja") 'cambia MiHoja por el nombre de la hoja que necesitas.

    With ws 'con esto harás referencia a esa hoja sólo poniendo un "." delante de los métodos
        Set C = .Cells.Find(what:=txtDni.Text, after:=.ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With
    With C 'C se refiere a la celda que has encontrado antes.
        Me.txtArea.Value = .Offset(0, 4).Value
        Me.txtCargo.Value = .Offset(0, 5).Value
        Me.txtEvaluador.Value = .Offset(0, 6).Value
        Me.txtFecIng.Value = .Offset(0, 3).Value
        Me.txtNombre.Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value
        Me.txtSede.Value = .Offset(0, 7).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Es increible como este tipo de comunidad te ayuda, agradezco mucho las respuestas Damian y Beto ; @Damian ya resolvi el problema gracias a tu aporte. Una ultima pregunta, si yo quiero insertar esos datos en otra hoja seria la misma logica al referenciar a la hoja?

Comment: sólo necesitas cambiar la lógica, en lugar de dar el valor a los textbox, se lo das a las celdas desde los textbox, @yonky

Answer (score -2):

Si deseas cambiar a una hoja en específico para trabajar sobre los datos de ella, la puedes activar así:

```
Sheets("NOMBRE DE LA HOJA").Select
```